# 405 Method not allowed POST, however it is allowed

Tags: java, http, soap, soapui, soap-client

I'm trying to send POST to some service. Inside the request body there is an XML.
I've tried to do it through SOAP UI - it works - just put inside body data the XML text. Through Jmeter - it works. through my own java code it returns me 405 - method not allowed.
I get 405 in Jmeter or SOAP UI if only I change method to GET.

So here's my code, where is POST method is definitely set. I have no idea what's wrong.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String soapEndpointUrl = "https://some.com/test";
    callSoapBankService(soapEndpointUrl);
}

private static void callSoapBankService(String soapEndpointUrl) {
    try {

        HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = null;
        // Open HTTPS connection
        URL url = new URL(soapEndpointUrl);
        httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Connect
        httpsConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpsConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpsConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "");
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "397");
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "some.com");
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)");
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(httpsConnection.getOutputStream());
            output.writeBytes("<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ws=\"http://some.com/\">\n" +
                    "                <SOAP-ENV:Header/>\n" +
                    "                <SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" +
                    "                    <ws:getDocument>\n" +
                    "                        <beginDate>2018-02-09</beginDate>\n" +
                    "                        <endDate>2018-02-10</endDate>\n" +
                    "                    </ws:getDocument>\n" +
                    "                </SOAP-ENV:Body>\n" +
                    "             </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");
         output.flush();
         output.close();
         DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(httpsConnection.getInputStream());
         for( int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read() )
         System.out.print( (char)c );
         input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

Comment: Maybe CSRF protection is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.The problem was at the end of this line:

String soapEndpointUrl = "https://some.com/test";

There should be a slash in URL